# Mapkit custom callout slide view from bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a map which has multiple Annotations on it. When I click one I want to slide a small UIView from the bottom with some information about this pin. If I click on a button called **more** I want the view to expand upwards with more information in it.

I'm not sure how to do this the right way. My idea is to define a new xib and view controller for the **custom callout**. But I only want to display a small portion of that view so should I set its frame from the beginning to a fixed small value or rather use autolayout to shrink it to its content? And how can I slide it up from the bottom? I think I need to show it either modally or as a childviewcontroller and use some animation.

When the user clicks on **more** I would use another **DetailViewController** with a xib file which either would be shown also modally or also as a childviewcontroller. Is there any example how to achieve something like this? Or are there any better ways to do this?

For now the **custom callout** view would be the same for each Annotation. But I would have three different **DetailViewControllers** depending on which Annotation was clicked.
My basic idea is to separate these things so my MapViewController won't get too big.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a view controller for the slide-in view.  Just create a UIView with a frame that's just outside of your main view frame, and make it a subview.  Like this:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:v];
self.infoView = v;
```

You can do that in viewDidLoad, or wherever you want in the initial setup of your view.  It won't be visible because it's just off the bottom of the screen.  Then when the user taps the callout button, animate your infoView into position like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // Populate infoView with whatever info you want to show about the annotation
    //
    //  ...
    //
    // Then animate the view into position
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"infoView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.infoView.center = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 200);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I like the idear with placing the callout view outside of the main view frame. However i need a callout view and three different types of detailed views (when the user decides to click "more" within the callout). I think it would to much to place everything within the same view controller. Is it possible to make the sliding with autolayout or better changing the frame?